# Localizing a list in Spring-MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, localization

what's the best way to localize a undefined list of strings? Ex:

```
key.for.list.line.1=Some text
key.for.list.line.2=Some text
key.for.list.line.3=Some text
...
```

I don't know how many rows I have. I would prefer something like this:

```
key.for.list=Some text \n
             Some text \n
             Some text
```

Thanks!

Comment: `\n` won't work with `HTML`, if needed in future

Comment: I was hopping for something like the special character for the arguments {0}